# How can I fix the issues caused by using column.insert to add a column in my VBA macro?

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone help me understand how I can update this VBA to change the output file to include an additional column and update an existing column header to reflect the following; "Add Delay Code" and "Remove Delay Code"? I believe I can achieve the need by updating the existing "Delay Code" field in Column G to "Add Delay Code" and shift the Columns H, I and J to the right so that Column H can become the new "Remove Delay Code" column. However, I'm a complete VBA n00b and I don't know where to start.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
Dim startcell As String
Dim Lastrow As String
Dim Lastrow2 As String
Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim ws As String
Dim Nws As String
Dim Nwo As String
Dim Firstcell As Integer
Dim Lastcell As String
Dim Firstrow As Integer
Dim WO1 As String
Dim WO2 As String
Dim WOlastROW As String
Dim StartTime As Date, EndTime As Date
Dim TimeTaken As Double

'
'StartTime = Time


Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

GetUserName = Application.UserName
Sheets("OUTLOOK DATA").Visible = True
Sheets("OUTLOOK DATA").Select
Range("A1").Select
Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Lastcell = "V" & (Lastrow)
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:" & (Lastcell)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "=*Crew*", Operator:=xlAnd
Rows("2:2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("D:M").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("E:K").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("F1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    OtherChar:="-", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(9, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("F:F").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("F:F").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("A1:E1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$E" & (Lastrow)), , xlYes).Name = _
    "Table1"
Range("Table1[#All]").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Sheets("OUTLOOK DATA").Select
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ws = ActiveSheet.Name
rowCount = 1
startcell = ("A1")
Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range(startcell, ("A" + (Lastrow))).Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:A" & (Lastrow)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

ws = ActiveSheet.Name
rowCount = 1
startcell = ("A1")
Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range(startcell, ("A" + (Lastrow))).Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(startcell, ("A" + (Lastrow))), , xlNo).Name = _
    "Table2"
Range("Table2[[#All],[Column1]]").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight1"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ws).ListObjects("Table2").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ws).ListObjects("Table2").Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("Table2[[#All],[Column1]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
    xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ws).ListObjects("Table2").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MATCH([@Column1],'OUTLOOK DATA'!C[-1],0)"
rowCount = 1
startcell = ("A2")
Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each i In Range(startcell, ("A" + (Lastrow)))
rowCount = rowCount + 1
Nwo = Cells((rowCount), 1).Value
Firstrow = Cells((rowCount), 2).Value
Secondrow = (Firstrow) + 1
Sheets("OUTLOOK DATA").Select
WO1 = Range("A" & (Firstrow))
WO2 = Range("A" & (Secondrow))
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    (Nwo)
Range("A" & (Firstrow)).Select
WOlastROW = Selection.End(xlDown).Row
If (WO1) = (WO2) Then
        Range("C" & (WOlastROW)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("C" & (Firstrow)).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
End If
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Next i

Sheets("OUTLOOK DATA").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Range("Table1[#All]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:= _
    xlYes
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OUTLOOK DATA").ListObjects("Table1").Sort. _
    SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OUTLOOK DATA").ListObjects("Table1").Sort. _
    SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[Subject]]"), SortOn:= _
    xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OUTLOOK DATA").ListObjects("Table1"). _
    Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Columns("B:C").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yy;@"
Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Subject]]").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Order"
Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Start Date]]").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Start"
Range("Table1[[#Headers],[End Date]]").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Finish"
Range("Table1[[#Headers],[column1]]").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "SCH Grade"

Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=IFS(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Hard Date"",[@Categories],1)),""B"",ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Firm Date"",[@Categories],1)),""C"",ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Flex Date"",[@Categories],1)),""D"")"
Range("Table1[SCH Grade]").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Cells.Replace What:="#N/A", Replacement:="D", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    
Columns("D:D").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Sheets("SAP DATA").Select

Range("Activity[[#Headers],[Suboperation]]") = "Start"

Range("Activity[[#Headers],[MaintenancePlan]]") = "Finish"

Range("Activity[[#Headers],[SystemCondition]]") = "Update User Status"

Range("Activity[[#Headers],[Description]]") = "SCH Grade Update"

Range("Activity[[#Headers],[Op.short text]]") = "Delay Code"

Range("Activity[[#Headers],[Op.System Cond.]]") = "Scheduler"

Range("C2:G3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents

Columns("E:G").NumberFormat = "General"
Columns("C:D").NumberFormat = "m/d/yy;@"

'Range("C2").Select
Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP([@Order],Table1,2,FALSE)"
'Columns("C:C").Select

'Range("D2").Select
Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP([@Order],Table1,3,FALSE)"

'Range("E2").Select
Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEFT([@[User status]],3)=""RSC"",""Yes"",""No"")"

'Range("F2").Select
Range("F2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP([@Order],Table1,4,FALSE)"

Range("Activity[[#Headers],[Order]:[Scheduler]]").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlNone
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With

Columns("I:K").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
Range("Activity[[#Headers],[Column1]]").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Delete"
Range("I2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF([@Start]=[@[Earl.start date]],""YES"","""")"
Range("Activity[[#Headers],[Column2]]").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Check"
Range("J2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF([@Finish]=[@EarliestEndDate],""YES"","""")"
Range("Activity[[#Headers],[Column3]]").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Goodbye"
Range("K2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS([@[Update User Status]],""No"",[@Delete],""YES"",[@Check],""YES"")"

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("AA1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(Activity[Goodbye],1)"


Sheets("SAP DATA").Select
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AA1") > 0 Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP DATA").ListObjects("Activity").Sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP DATA").ListObjects("Activity").Sort.SortFields. _
    Add2 Key:=Range("Activity[[#All],[Goodbye]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
    Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP DATA").ListObjects("Activity").Sort
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Activity").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:= _
    "1"
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    
End If
Range("A2").Select

Columns("I:I").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Range("Activity[Scheduler]") = GetUserName

Columns("A:H").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Range("J2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "S:\LDC-LI\Central Scheduling Folder\Outlook Exports\Bot Intake Form"
Range("J1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Copy data to file destination below"
Range("J1:J2").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Range("J1").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
    .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Range("J1:J2").Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With

Columns("J:J").Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 75

Range("Activity[[#Headers],[Order]]").Select

Range("Activity[[#Headers],[Order]]").Select
Sheets("Macro Controls").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Sheets("OUTLOOK DATA").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete


Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'EndTime = Time

SAVE

'TimeTaken = (EndTime - StartTime) * 24 * 60 * 60
'MsgBox TimeTaken

End Sub

Private Sub SAVE()
'
' Creating a new book in which to place schedules

' Thanks Shawn for your Googling expertise 12-12-17

' Tuesday is officially "BREAKTHROUGH DAY"

USID = Environ("UserName")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\" & (USID) & "\Desktop\" & "BOT DATA DROP" & ".xlsx", FileFormat _
    :=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:= _
    False, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
Sub GetWorkorderNumbers()

Dim Lastrow As String
Dim NewLastrow As String
'
Sheets("Outlook Data").Select

Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("AA1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=True, OtherChar:= _
    "&", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), _
    Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers _
    :=True
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("AB:AC").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A1:B1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2nd WO"
Columns("AB:AB").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Range("B2:W" & Lastrow).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B" & Lastrow).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
NewLastrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("B" & Lastrow & ":B" & NewLastrow).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A" & Lastrow).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("B:B").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Sheets("Macro Controls").Select

Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("WOnumbers").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "<>1*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("WOnumbers").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("WOnumbers[#All]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:= _
    xlYes
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("WOnumbers[[#Headers],[Order Numbers]]").Select

Sheets("OUTLOOK DATA").Visible = False
Sheets("SAP DATA").Visible = True

End Sub
```

I've tried to add the column with column.insert code, and it caused everything to go haywire. I am feeling like this code is too complex for a simple fix. This is also a 'part 2' macros I have to another 'part 1' macros that formats data from Microsoft Outlook to align with data that comes from SAP in 'part 2'.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the problem you face (because frankly I am not gonna try understanding your code - this wall of code is just too much - a procedure this long shoudn't really exist, you'd usually try and split different functionalities into subs and functions.)

But now to what I think could be the issue you are facing. When inserting you are changing what Columns are where. If you insert 1 Column after Column A; Column B will now be Column C and so on. This will then screw up possible references to Column B or C (or any other Column greater than A) - This is why, when inserting Rows and Columns you usually start with the biggest and work back from there. For example say you want to insert a column after A, D and F. Then you'd start by inserting the Column after F, then D and at last A. This way subsequent insert operations will not be affected by the shifting of columns caused by other insert operations.

Comment: Thank you for helping me better understand some of the issues that the guy who handed this off to me created by building it all into one large sub to execute some 30+ functions.